# Dialogflow detect audio with express not work

Tags: javascript, express, dialogflow-es

I tried to save the audio file from client and sent it to dialogflow for detection. But I couldn't get any error message. SessionClient works fine if I move out of req.pipe(). The request is a wav file.

```
router.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {
  var timeCode = new Date();
  const filename = 'public/voiceFiles/' + timeCode.getTime() + '.wav';
  req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename))
    .on('error', (e) => res.status(500).end(e.message))
    .on('close', () => {
      const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
      readFile(filename)
        .then(inputAudio => {
          // The audio query request
          const request = {
            session: sessionPath,
            queryInput: {
              audioConfig: {
                audioEncoding: encoding,
                sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
                languageCode: languageCode,
              },
            },
            inputAudio: inputAudio,
          };
          // Recognizes the speech in the audio and detects its intent.
          return sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
        })
        .then(responses => {
          console.log('Detected intent:');
          res.end(JSON.stringify(responses));
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error('ERROR:', err);
          res.end(err)
        });
      // [END dialogflow_detect_intent_audio]      
    })
});
```